# javascript test function return always false

Tags: javascript, regex, testing

I don't understand why it is giving me false while the two strings are equal.

```
var str = 'https:\/\/monsite.com\/"onload="alert(1)"';
var patt = /https:\/\/monsite.com\/"onload="alert(1)"/i;
var result = patt.test(str);
document.write("Returned value: " + result);
```

I am a new beginner.

Comment: It could be the parentheses in your regex.

Comment: @kirowaxoaw, yes you do, surrounding the number `1`.

Answer (score 6):

You need to escape parentheses inside Regex they are special characters.

```
/https:\/\/monsite.com\/"onload="alert\(1\)"/
```